# Working with meeting invitations in the Inbox

Tags: c#, outlook, invitation

I would like to show a region within the Outlook meeting invitation dialog where the details of all meetings that conflict with the current meeting are listed. I believe I have all the code except to sense when an item in the Inbox is of type meeting. The form region is created in the Mail.IPM. I have tried both the MeetingItem and AppointmentItem types with no success. 
What item type should I be looking for ? Btw, writing code in C#.

Answer (score 0):

Meeting request are of type `IPM.Schedule.Meeting.Request`.